# knockout not displaying images bound to the img element

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying a sample to get started with it. Basics given by the official site are working fine. But I have tried a sample 
example which is not working as expected. 
Can someone suggest me the right direction to make the below sample work?

Here is my ViewModel

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js" />

function ImagesModelForEachRow(image1, image2, image3) {
var self = this;
self.image1 =  ko.observable(image1);
self.image2 = ko.observable(image2);
self.image3 = ko.observable(image3);

}

var ImagesListModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.ImagesArray = ko.observableArray([]);
self.GetImagesList = function () {
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "ImageDisplay.aspx/getallImages",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: fnsuccesscallback,
        error: fnerrorcallback
    });

    function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
        $.each(data.d.ImagesList, function (idx, val) {
            debugger;
            self.ImagesArray.push(new ImagesModelForEachRow(val.Image1, val.Image2, val.Image3));
        });


    }
    function fnerrorcallback(result) {
        alert(result.statusText);
    }
}


}

$(document).ready(function () {

debugger;

var v = new ImagesListModel();
ko.applyBindings(v);

});
```

My View layer:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImageDisplay.aspx.cs"     Inherits="Sample.ImageDisplay" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ImagesDisplay.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<div id="ImagesSCreen">
        <input type="button" data-bind="click: GetImagesList" value="Search" />
        <table border="2" >
            <tbody>
                   <tr>

                    <td>

                        <img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Images/'+$data.ImagesArray()[0].image2()+'.png'}" ></img>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Images/'+$data.ImagesArray()[0].image2()+'.png'}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Images/'+$data.ImagesArray()[0].image2()+'.png'}"></img>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Model layer(which is my .cs file):

```
namespace Sample
{
public partial class ImageDisplay : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string Image1 = "image1";
    public static string Image2 = "image2";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public static ListOfImages getallImages()
    {

        Images images1 = new Images();
        images1.Image1 = "image1";
        images1.Image2 = "image1";
        images1.Image3 = "image1";

        Images Images2 = new Images();
        Images2.Image1 = "image2";
        Images2.Image2 = "image2";
        Images2.Image3 = "image2";

        ListOfImages list = new ListOfImages();
        list.ImagesList = new List<Images>();
        list.ImagesList.Add(images1);
        list.ImagesList.Add(Images2);

        return list;

    }
}
public class ListOfImages
{
    public List<Images> ImagesList;
}
public class Images
{
    public string Image1 { set; get; }
    public string Image2 { set; get; }
    public string Image3 { set; get; }

}
}
```

**What I am expecting the result would be:** The browser renders three images for the three td elements

**What actually is the result:** Only one image is being rendered and the 2nd and 3rd images are no longer shown.

Even I tried giving a span element with $data.ImagesArray()[0].image2() as text for it after the td element. Even this was not shown.

I checked console in IE and it is giving error as

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'image2': object is null or undefined 
ImageDisplay.aspx, line 2 character 57
```

As far as I read since image2 is an observable it should be called as a function. I tried even calling it simply as a property.

Can someone help me understanding the issue with this code?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: After checking errors in the console as suggested by PW, the next step is to right click on the generated element and select Inspect Element to see what HTML knockout generated.

Comment: Which line of your code is: ImageDisplay.aspx, line 2 character 57?

Comment: It is <DocType... line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my table tag to the below one.

```
<table border="2" data-bind="ifnot: ImagesArray().length == 0">
```

In addition to this removed unnecessary spans and it solved my issue.

Comment: Hi G_S, do you understand why this solved your problem?

Comment: Yes Chuck Schneider. When the page first tries to render the html, ImagesArray would be empty. So it doesnt have image1 property. This is causing the object is null or undefined exception. Do you feel its not right? Please inform if I am thinking wrong

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct. I usually get around this by use a with: or an if: binding. That is, I would define self.ImagesArray = ko.observableArray(); (note, no []) then do a with:ImagesArray or if:ImagesArray. When your ajax call fills the array, KO will populate the DOM

Comment: Just curious to know.Can you please let me know what is difference between declaring it as observableArray () and observableArray([])?

Comment: I believe that if you add the [], you have an empty array and would need to check the length as you did. If you leave that off, data-bind:"with: ImagesArray" or if:ImagesArray evaluate to false until you  initialize the array in the ajax success callback...I think...I haven't tried this in a fiddle. But that would be my guess as to the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

OH, just noticed, Your syntax for your img tags are incorrect. There's no such thing as `</img>`. You need to remove that. Try:

```
 <td>
    <img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Images/'+$data.ImagesArray()[0].image2()+'.png'}" >
  </td>
  <td>
      <img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Images/'+$data.ImagesArray()[0].image2()+'.png'}">
  </td>
  <td>
   <img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Images/'+$data.ImagesArray()[0].image2()+'.png'}">
  </td>
```

Comment: If this fixes your problem, please accept the answer or let us know otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Chuck for replying. I tried it but it dint solve the issue. Please kindly look into the edited question.